# How to inject a value from properties file in a method level annotation in spring?

Tags: spring, annotations

We need to Inject a property into a method annotation.

```
    @MyAnno(someproperty = @Value("${someproperty}"))
    public muMethod{

    }
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is that the value is injected as class variable.